# PHP XML generation, chain `appendChild()`

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm generating an XML file via PHP and I'm doing it this way:

```
$dom  = new DOMDocument();
$root = $dom->createElement('Root');
...
// some node definitions here etc
$root->appendChild($product);
$root->appendChild($quantity);
$root->appendChild($measureUnit);
$root->appendChild($lineNumber);
...
$dom->appendChild($root);
$dom->save( '/some/dir/some-name.xml');
```

It all works well until I encountered some *problem*, when I get to the part that I needed to append lets say `N` child nodes. This meant that I would be calling the function `appendChild()` `'N'` times too - and that resulted on a very long php script which is a little hard to maintain.

I know we can split the main script on smaller files for better maintenance but are there better ways to just 'chain' the 'appendChild' calls so it would save as a lot of written lines or is there a somewhat magic function such as 'appendChildren' available?

This is my first time using the `DOMDocument()` class, I hope someone can shed me some light.

Thank you

Comment: No, you can not chain appendChild calls, because that method returns the node that was appended, and not the node that you appended to.

Comment: You can of course stick all your nodes that you need to append into an array first - and then you loop over that array, and call appendChild for the current node inside the loop body.

Comment: Oh thanks! Yes, we're just looping it in an array for the meantime. I really thought we were doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the `DOMDocument::createElement()` into `DOMNode::appendChild()` calls and chain child nodes or text content assignments.

Since PHP 8.0 `DOMNode::append()` can be used to append multiple nodes and strings.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
// nest createElement inside appendChild
$document->appendChild(
    // store node in variable
    $root = $document->createElement('root')
);

// chain textContent assignment to appendChild
$root
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('product'))
  ->textContent = 'Example';
  
// use append to add multiple nodes  
$root->append(
  $product = $document->createElement('measureUnit'),
  $quantity = $document->createElement('quantity'),  
);
$product->textContent = 'cm';
$quantity->textContent = '42';


$document->formatOutput= true;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <product>Example</product>
  <measureUnit>cm</measureUnit>
  <quantity>42</quantity>
</root>
```

I am using an interface for reusable and maintainable parts, usually:

```
interface XMLAppendable {
    
    public function appendTo(DOMElement $parent): void;
    
}

class YourXMLPart implements XMLAppendable {
    
    private $_product;
    private $_unit;
    private $_quantity;
    
    public function __construct(string $product, string $unit, int $quantity) {
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_unit = $unit;
        $this->_quantity = $quantity;
    }
    
    public function appendTo(DOMElement $parent): void {
        $document = $parent->ownerDocument; 
        $parent
            ->appendChild($document->createElement('product'))
            ->textContent = $this->_product;
        $parent
            ->appendChild($document->createElement('measureUnit'))
            ->textContent = $this->_unit;
        $parent
            ->appendChild($document->createElement('quantity'))
            ->textContent = $this->_quantity;
    }
}


$document = new DOMDocument();
// nest createElement inside appendChild
$document->appendChild(
    // store node in variable
    $root = $document->createElement('root')
);
$part = new YourXMLPart('Example', 'cm', 42);
$part->appendTo($root);

$document->formatOutput= true;
echo $document->saveXML();
```